# Spliting string in column by seperator and adding those as new columns in the same data frame using R

Tags: r

I have a column in dataframe `df` with value `'name>year>format'`. Now I want to split this column by `>` and add those values to new columns named as `name`, `year`, `format`. How can I do this in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily using separate function in tidyr;

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    A = c("Joe>1993>student")
  )

data %>%
  separate(A, into = c("name", "year", "format"), sep = ">", remove = FALSE)

# A name year  format
# Joe>1993>student  Joe 1993 student
```

If you do not want the original column in the result dataframe change remove to TRUE

Answer (score 1):

An option is `read.table` in `base R`

```
cbind(df, read.table(text = as.character(df$column), sep=">", 
         header = FALSE, col.names = c("name", "year", "format")))
```

Comment: In case I have 3 different columns to split like this I do the same thrice ?

Comment: @SNT You can create a function and apply or use it in `lapply` i.e. `lapply(df[1:3], function(x) read.table(text = as.character(x), sep=">", 
         header = FALSE, col.names = c('one', 'two', 'three')))`

Answer (score 1):

In case your data is big, it would be a good idea to use `data.table` as it is very fast.

### If you know how many fields your "combined" column has:

Suppose the column has 3 fields, **and you know it**:

```
library(data.table)

# the 1:3 should be replaced by 1:n, where n is the number of fields
dt1[, paste0("V", 1:3) := tstrsplit(y, split = ">", fixed = TRUE)]
```

### If you DON'T know in advance how many fields the column has:

Now we can get some help from the `stringi` package:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

maxFields <- dt2[, max(stri_count_fixed(y, ">")) + 1]
dt2[, paste0("V", 1:maxFields) := tstrsplit(y, split = ">", fixed = TRUE, fill = NA)]
```

### Data used:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(x = c("A", "B"), y = c("letter>2018>pdf", "code>2020>Rmd"))

dt2 <- rbind(dt1, data.table(x = "C", y = "report>2019>html>pdf"))
```